# TypeScript keeps transpiling away async/await even with target: es2017

Tags: javascript, typescript, async-await

Consider this test script.

```
#!/bin/bash -ex

rm -rf ts-async-await
mkdir ts-async-await
cd ts-async-await
npm init -y &> /dev/null
npm i --save-dev typescript@4.7.4 &> /dev/null
echo "async function x() { return 1; }" > test.ts
echo '{ "compilerOptions": { "target": "es2017" } }' > tsconfig.json
npx tsc --version
npx tsc --showConfig
npx tsc test.ts
cat tsconfig.json
cat test.js
```

I'm creating an empty directory with a single one-liner TypeScript file, containing async/await.

```js
async function x() { return 1; }
```

Then, I'm creating a `tsconfig.json` where the `compilerOptions` `target` is set to `es2017`.

```json
{ "compilerOptions": { "target": "es2017" } }
```

`tsc --showConfig` shows:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es2017"
    },
    "files": [
        "./test.ts"
    ]
}
```

Then, I'm transpiling my `test.ts` file to `test.js`.

Expected: This one-liner should transpile cleanly to a one-liner JS file, just like it does in the TypeScript playground https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/IYZwngdgxgBAZgV2gFwJYHsIwB4AoCUMA3jAE4CmyCpWAjANwwC+QA

Actual: TypeScript generates 40 lines of code, downgrading my `async/await` code into non-`async/await` code with the `__awaiter` and `__generator` helpers.

How do I make my sample TypeScript project do what the playground does? Why isn't `target` doing the right thing for me here?

Here's the full log of the test output:

```
+ rm -rf ts-async-await
+ mkdir ts-async-await
+ cd ts-async-await
+ npm init -y
+ npm i --save-dev typescript@4.7.4
+ echo 'async function x() { return 1; }'
+ echo '{ "compilerOptions": { "target": "es2017" } }'
+ npx tsc --version
Version 4.7.4
+ npx tsc --showConfig
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es2017"
    },
    "files": [
        "./test.ts"
    ]
}
+ npx tsc test.ts
+ cat tsconfig.json
{ "compilerOptions": { "target": "es2017" } }
+ cat test.js
var __awaiter = (this && this.__awaiter) || function (thisArg, _arguments, P, generator) {
    function adopt(value) { return value instanceof P ? value : new P(function (resolve) { resolve(value); }); }
    return new (P || (P = Promise))(function (resolve, reject) {
        function fulfilled(value) { try { step(generator.next(value)); } catch (e) { reject(e); } }
        function rejected(value) { try { step(generator["throw"](value)); } catch (e) { reject(e); } }
        function step(result) { result.done ? resolve(result.value) : adopt(result.value).then(fulfilled, rejected); }
        step((generator = generator.apply(thisArg, _arguments || [])).next());
    });
};
var __generator = (this && this.__generator) || function (thisArg, body) {
    var _ = { label: 0, sent: function() { if (t[0] & 1) throw t[1]; return t[1]; }, trys: [], ops: [] }, f, y, t, g;
    return g = { next: verb(0), "throw": verb(1), "return": verb(2) }, typeof Symbol === "function" && (g[Symbol.iterator] = function() { return this; }), g;
    function verb(n) { return function (v) { return step([n, v]); }; }
    function step(op) {
        if (f) throw new TypeError("Generator is already executing.");
        while (_) try {
            if (f = 1, y && (t = op[0] & 2 ? y["return"] : op[0] ? y["throw"] || ((t = y["return"]) && t.call(y), 0) : y.next) && !(t = t.call(y, op[1])).done) return t;
            if (y = 0, t) op = [op[0] & 2, t.value];
            switch (op[0]) {
                case 0: case 1: t = op; break;
                case 4: _.label++; return { value: op[1], done: false };
                case 5: _.label++; y = op[1]; op = [0]; continue;
                case 7: op = _.ops.pop(); _.trys.pop(); continue;
                default:
                    if (!(t = _.trys, t = t.length > 0 && t[t.length - 1]) && (op[0] === 6 || op[0] === 2)) { _ = 0; continue; }
                    if (op[0] === 3 && (!t || (op[1] > t[0] && op[1] < t[3]))) { _.label = op[1]; break; }
                    if (op[0] === 6 && _.label < t[1]) { _.label = t[1]; t = op; break; }
                    if (t && _.label < t[2]) { _.label = t[2]; _.ops.push(op); break; }
                    if (t[2]) _.ops.pop();
                    _.trys.pop(); continue;
            }
            op = body.call(thisArg, _);
        } catch (e) { op = [6, e]; y = 0; } finally { f = t = 0; }
        if (op[0] & 5) throw op[1]; return { value: op[0] ? op[1] : void 0, done: true };
    }
};
function x() {
    return __awaiter(this, void 0, void 0, function () { return __generator(this, function (_a) {
        return [2 /*return*/, 1];
    }); });
}
```

Comment: Show your tsconfig?

Comment: My tsconfig is right there in the script. Just to make it clearer, I copied and pasted it outside the script, too.

Comment: Look at your script again. Count the number of opening and closing braces. That's why I asked you to show your tsconfig: you wrote a file, open that file in your code editor, and then look at the error you immediately get because it's malformed.

Comment: And now that you've edited your code to something _very different_: does it still go wrong or did you just fix your problem by fixing your missing curly brace?

Comment: No, fixing the curly brace didn't fix anything.

Comment: Indeed, somehow `tsc` didn't care about the missing brace; `tsc --showConfig` showed `"target": "es2017"` anyway. But now that the brace is fixed, it still definitely doesn't work. (Does my script work for you now?)

Comment: Before I check: which version of typescript are you using here?

Comment: Run my script; I'm using that version of TypeScript! (It turns out to be 4.7.4, the current latest.)

Comment: Please put that in your post: as obvious as you think you're being, `npx` _does not install anything_ if you already have a package.json and have tsc installed through that, it simply runs "Whatever is in your node_modules already", and an on-the-spot version can be different every time `npx` runs. So folks need to know what you're using, because that's an important detail.

Comment: It's great that you've produced a script that reproduces your problem, but not everybody wants to `npm install` things to help you, and as time goes on, the versions your script installs will change. You need to include this information in your question, explicitly.

Comment: Now I've pinned a version, and I'm logging the version number, and I'm demonstrating the log output right there in the question. Is my question acceptable now?

Comment: Yes: now it's a [mcve] that folks can verify.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Typescript *either* runs as a CLI invocation on a file, *or* on a config that specifies the entry point, but not both (try running `npx tsc test.js --p tsconfig.js` and look at the output you get).

As such, this will work just fine:

```
> npx tsc test.ts --target esnext
```

and this will also work just fine:

```
> npx tsc
```

or with explicit reference to the config file:

```
> npx tsc --p tsconfig.json
```

But because you're calling `npx tsc test.ts` in your script, typescript is going to completely ignore your config file and just run what you told it to do *purely* in your CLI statement.

Comment: Wow, what a footgun! I have no idea how I would have figured this out without posting a test script and a StackOverflow question like this.

Comment: My approach was "this script indeed does the wrong thing. The config looks fine. Is it _using_ the config at all? Let's explicitly add that as flag to the command line. Ah, right, yes that error makes sense, the config already says which file to start on".

Comment: This is filed as https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/27379 There was initially some questions about how this should be implemented, but consensus has been reached. It seems likely that a PR would be welcome.